# How can I call multiple eventTypes in one function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services

I have written the following function in my service:

```
public refresh(area: string) {
    this.eventEmitter.emit({ area });
  }
```

`area` accesses all my childs and should update them in the parent with a click.

// In Childs

```
this.myService.eventEmitter.subscribe((data) => {
      if (!this.isLoading && data.area === 'childFirst') {
        this.loadData();
      }
    });
```

```
this.myService.eventEmitter.subscribe((data) => {
      if (!this.isLoading && data.area === 'childSecond') {
        this.loadData();
      }
    });
```

```
this.myService.eventEmitter.subscribe((data) => {
      if (!this.isLoading && data.area === 'childThird') {
        this.loadData();
      }
    });
```

// My Parent-Component

```
// TS
 showChildFirst() {
    this.navService.sendNavEventUpdate('childFirst');
  }

  showChildSecond() {
    this.navService.sendNavEventUpdate('childSecond');
  }

  showChildThird() {
    this.navService.sendNavEventUpdate('childThird');
  }

 public refresh(area: string) {
    this.myService.refresh(area);
  }
```

```
// HTML
<!-- Refresh your childs -->
<button type="button" (click)="refresh()">Refresh</button>
```

If I insert the following into the function: `refresh('childFirst')` the first child component is updated. Is there a way to refresh all eventTypes in refresh?

Comment: I miss the connection between `myService.eventEmitter` and `showChildFirst` method. I suppose there is `myService.eventEmitter.subscribe` at some place which would help to answer this question

Comment: I will now update my code

Comment: my code is updated

Comment: now I'm even more confused :D do you want to load data no matter which argument is emitted by `myService.eventEmitter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your 'refresh' method to get an array of strings instead of a single string. So the method would become

```
 public refresh(areas: string[]) {
    areas.forEach(area =>
        this.myService.refresh(area);
    )
  }
```

and calling it would be

```
<button type="button" (click)="refresh(['childFirst','childSecond','childThird'])">Refresh</button>
```

Comment: Typo in Array.forEach()